# How to handle multiple empty Values in SpringWebFlux using zip operator

Tags: spring, spring-webflux

Im wiling to ask u how can i handle situations where i call 5 repositories method in async way and then i need to zip all of them to make a object of it, but i dont want to block each of request instead i want to block only one i tryed diffrent approach as i readed about them for example, converting to Mono and then ziping all of them but it still doesnt works

```
 public Mono<ServerResponse> addOrUpdateBlog(ServerRequest serverRequest) {
        String jwt = serverRequest.headers().firstHeader(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION);
        return serverRequest.body(BodyExtractors.toMultipartData())
                .flatMap(multiValueMap -> {
                    if (multiValueMap.containsKey("blogRequest")) {
                        return multiValueMap.getFirst("blogRequest").content().map(dataBuffer -> {
                                    byte[] bytes = new byte[dataBuffer.readableByteCount()];
                                    dataBuffer.read(bytes);
                                    DataBufferUtils.release(dataBuffer);
                                    return new String(bytes, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
                                }).collectList()
                                .flatMap(stringList -> {
                                    try {
                                        CreateBlogRequest createBlogRequest = new ObjectMapper().readValue(String.join("", stringList), CreateBlogRequest.class);
                                        if (multiValueMap.containsKey("imageFile"))
                                            createBlogRequest.setImageFile((FilePart) multiValueMap.getFirst("imageFile"));
                                        return Mono.just(createBlogRequest);
                                    } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
                                        return Mono.error(new BlogException("Fail to parse json request!"));
                                    }
                                });
                    } else {
                        CreateBlogRequest createSlideRequest = new CreateBlogRequest();
                        createSlideRequest.setImageFile((FilePart) multiValueMap.getFirst("imageFile"));
                        return Mono.just(createSlideRequest);
                    }
                })
                .flatMap(createBlogRequest -> {
                    validationUtils.validateRequest(createBlogRequest);

                    Mono<User> userMono = userRepository.findById(tokenService.getUserIdFromToken(jwt))
                            .switchIfEmpty(Mono.error(new BadCredentialsException("Invalid token received!")));


                    Mono<Category> categoryMono = Mono.justOrEmpty(createBlogRequest.getCategoryId())
                            .flatMap(categoryId -> categoryRepository.findById(categoryId)
                                    .switchIfEmpty(Mono.error(new ResourceNotFoundException("Category not found!")))
                            );

                    Mono<List<Tag>> tagListMono = Mono.justOrEmpty(createBlogRequest.getTagsId())
                            .filter(tagsId -> !tagsId.isEmpty())
                            .flatMap(tagsId -> tagRepository.findAllById(tagsId)
                                    .collectList()
                                    .flatMap(tags -> {
                                        if (tags.size() <= tagsId.size())
                                            return Mono.error(new ResourceNotFoundException("Invalid tag input!"));
                                        return Mono.just(tags);
                                    })
                            );

                    Mono<String> imageName = Mono.justOrEmpty(createBlogRequest.getImageFile())
                            .flatMap(imageFile -> Mono.just(imageFile.filename() + UUID.randomUUID())
                                    .flatMap(name -> {
                                        imageFile.transferTo(Paths.get(uploadDir + "/static/" + name));
                                        return Mono.just(name);
                                    })
                            );

                    Mono<Blog> blogMono = Mono.justOrEmpty(createBlogRequest.getBlogId())
                            .flatMap(blogId -> blogRepository.findById(blogId)
                                    .switchIfEmpty(Mono.error(new ResourceNotFoundException("Blog with id " + blogId + " doesn't exist!")))
                            );
                    System.out.println("pre zipa");
                    return Mono.zip(userMono,categoryMono)
                            .map(tuple -> {
                                System.out.println("u zipu");
                                Map<String, Object> map = new LinkedHashMap<>();
                                map.put("user", tuple.getT1());
                                map.put("tags", tuple.getT2());
                                return Mono.just(map);
                            })
                            .block();
                })
```

im expected to combine all of them and create new blog object, all of the values can be nulll depdends on is it update session or create session, also i tried making all optional and blocking the map that i made but doesnt helps me.

Comment: "handle"? handle them how? you can handle things in 100 different ways, returning an error, having default value, trying a different repository, you are just asking how you should handle but not describing how you want it to be handled

Comment: i want to make object of Blog with all these components, and sometimes i want to update a blog when there is blogId, but i can make it sync and i dont want to use 5 times block becaues it is called 'bad practice' isnt it?

Answer (score 0):

So affter some timis digging and trying i was able to solve the issue , so the answer was to map everythiing to Optional then to zip every mono using Mono.zip and then peform the block operation on Mono.zip

```
 .map(createBlogRequest -> {
                   validationUtils.validateRequest(createBlogRequest);

                   var userMono = userRepository.findById(tokenService.getUserIdFromToken(jwt))
                            .switchIfEmpty(Mono.error(new ResourceNotFoundException("User not found!")));

                   var categoryMono = Mono.justOrEmpty(createBlogRequest.getCategoryId())
                                          .flatMap(categoryId -> categoryRepository.findById(categoryId)
                                                  .switchIfEmpty(Mono.error(new ResourceNotFoundException("Category not found!")))
                                          )
                                          .map(Optional::of)
                                          .defaultIfEmpty(Optional.empty());

                   var tagListMono = Mono.justOrEmpty(createBlogRequest.getTagsId())
                                         .filter(tagsId -> !tagsId.isEmpty())
                                         .flatMap(tagsId -> tagRepository.findAllById(tagsId)
                                                 .collectList()
                                                 .flatMap(tags -> {
                                                    if (tags.size() <= tagsId.size())
                                                        return Mono.error(new ResourceNotFoundException("Invalid tag input!"));
                                                    return Mono.just(tags);
                                                })
                                         )
                                        .map(Optional::of)
                                        .defaultIfEmpty(Optional.empty());

                   var imageNameMono = Mono.justOrEmpty(createBlogRequest.getImageFile())
                                           .flatMap(imageFile -> Mono.just(imageFile.filename() + UUID.randomUUID())
                                                   .flatMap(name -> {
                                                       imageFile.transferTo(Paths.get(uploadDir + "/static/" + name));
                                                       return Mono.just(name);
                                                   })
                                           )
                                           .map(Optional::of)
                                           .defaultIfEmpty(Optional.empty());

                   var blogMono = Mono.justOrEmpty(createBlogRequest.getBlogId())
                                       .flatMap(blogRepository::findById)
                                       .switchIfEmpty(Mono.error(new ResourceNotFoundException("Blog not found!")))
                                       .map(Optional::of)
                                       .defaultIfEmpty(Optional.empty());


                   var tuple =  Mono.zip(userMono, categoryMono, tagListMono, imageNameMono,blogMono).block();

                    Blog blog = tuple.getT5().get();
```